# How to pass only second argument of a bind function?

Tags: c++, bind, eventemitter, handlers

I'm using a generic [EventEmitter](https://gist.github.com/martinfinke/a636dcddbcf112344b59) instance:

```
EventEmitter mEventHandler;
```

So I've defined this bind:

```
function<void(int, double)> onSetMin = bind(&ILFO::SetMin, this, placeholders::_2);
mEventHandler.on(kParamID, onSetMin);
```

and the `on` such as:

```
mEventHandler.emit(paramID, someInt, someDouble);
```

which is "generic" as said, and set 2 params. But my specific function `SetMin` need just one param (which would be `someDouble` in this case):

```
void ILFO::SetMin(double min);
```

How would you just pass second paramter from bind?

Comment: You can pass extra parameters to the function object returned from bind. They are silently ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to use a lambda for your problem I think:

```
function<void(int, double)> onSetMin = [this](int dummy, double d) { SetMin(d); };
mEventHandler.on(kParamID, onSetMin);
```

Comment: You makes my day! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

According to *C++ reference* in the `std::bind` call you can use

> unbound arguments replaced by the placeholders _1, _2, _3... of
>   namespace std::placeholders

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

> ```
> using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2, _3...
> // demonstrates argument reordering and pass-by-reference
> int n = 7;
> // (_1 and _2 are from std::placeholders, and represent future
> // arguments that will be passed to f1)
> auto f1 = std::bind(f, _2, 42, _1)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda instead of `std::bind`:

```
mEventHandler.on(kParamID, [this] (int, double value) {
    SetMin(value);
});
```

The purpose of `std::bind` is the opposite of what you want to do: It helps you create a function taking `N` arguments from a function `f` taking `M` where `M > N` by fixing some arguments of `f` to given values (or/and change the order of the arguments).